# Multiplicative property of the functional determinant

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, functional-determinants

If we consider two differential operators $\mathcal{D}_1$ and $\mathcal{D}_2$, we can compose them to create the differential operator $\mathcal{D}_1 \mathcal{D}_2$. Then we could consider an action (introducing the bosonic degrees of freedom $\phi$)
$$
S[\phi]=\int d^d x  \ \phi \mathcal{D}_1 \mathcal{D}_2 \phi \ ,
$$
and consider the partition function given by the (Euclidean) path integral
$$
\mathcal{Z}=\int [d \phi] e^{-\int d^d x  \ \phi \mathcal{D}_1 \mathcal{D}_2 \phi} \ .
$$
Now, this partition function can be formally evaluated as (up to numerical factors)
$$
\mathcal{Z} \simeq \det (\mathcal{D}_1 \mathcal{D}_2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \ .
$$
If we consider two square matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$, then we know that the famous multiplicativity property of the determinant holds
$$
\det(A_1 A_2)=\det(A_2 A_1)=\det(A_1)\det(A_2) \ .
$$
My question is the following: is it possible that, under specific hypotheses, the functional determinant $\det(\mathcal{D}_1 \mathcal{D}_2)$ enjoys the same properties and
$$
\det(\mathcal{D}_1 \mathcal{D}_2)=\det(\mathcal{D}_2 \mathcal{D}_1)=\det(\mathcal{D}_1)\det(\mathcal{D}_2) \ ?
$$
If the question above has a positive answer, which hypotheses must be satisfied?